# binary_log_types.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, mysql, c

I was compiling a small mysql C project and 
got stuck with the below error :

```
 C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\include/mysql_com.h:22:30: fatal error: binary_log_types.h: No such file or directory.
```

I did a `dir binary_log_types.h /b /s` at `C:` drive but i didn't find any binary_log_types.h file as such. 
What is a possible workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a bit of research I figured out that for some reason the two files `binary_log_funcs.h` and `binary_log_types.h` are missing from the mysql 5.7 community installer installation.

**Fix :**

1) Download the MySQL Server Source code from the [MySQL Site](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file.php?id=456917).

2) Extract the the tar archive. ( I used Winrar for this)

3) Goto Your\Download\Location\Here\mysql-5.7.7-rc\mysql-5.7.7-rc\libbinlogevents\export\

4) Copy the `binary_log_funcs.h` and `binary_log_types.h` from this folder and 
   paste them in Path\to\your\mysql\server\include.

5) Rebuild the Code::Blocks application.

**Note :** Make sure that Code::Blocks has the permission to access the the files and folders in the C: directory. Also, this could be a temporary fix as I strongly feel that I didn't do a complete mysql installation which should automatically include these files. Anyway I am temporarily happy :)

Answer (score 2):

Just confirmed the existence of this bug in MySQL 5.7.9 (64bit) as well:

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\include\mysql_com.h(22): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'binary_log_types.h': No such file or directory`
```

I got this error message while compiling in Visual Studio 2013 Update 5, code based on communication with MySQL to store data in a database.

My solution is a variant of sjsam's own answer. Go to the GitHub MySQL repository and open this folder/directory:

https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/5.7/libbinlogevents/export/ :

There are 2 files in that folder:

- binary_log_funcs.h
- binary_log_types.h

Save the 2 files to your own computer by using the file links (or copy the text from the file contents, then save the text to straight text files with the same names as the originals), then put both files in your MySQL Server 5.7\include\ folder. Depending on your configuration, this can be one of these 2:

`C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\include\`

`C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\include\`

Congratulations, you have now solved your issue. But I am wondering why the developers at mysql.com haven't added those 2 files to the MySQL Community Server 5.7.9 installer package...

Answer (score 0):

the following statement, from: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/binary-log.html

indicates the mysql server must be started with the right parameter

for the log to exist.

"To enable the binary log, start the server with the --log-bin[=base_name] option. If no base_name value is given, the default name is the value of the pid-file option (which by default is the name of host machine) followed by -bin. If the basename is given, the server writes the file in the data directory unless the basename is given with a leading absolute path name to specify a different directory. It is recommended that you specify a basename explicitly rather than using the default of the host name; see Section B.5.8, “Known Issues in MySQL”, for the reason. "

There is lots of related info at that same web page.

Comment: Thankyou for your time. I have already enabled binary logging and still it didn't fix the issue.  Any idea where to get a copy of the `binary_log_types.h` file?